# Value from iterative function in pandas

Tags: pandas, function, numpy, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe and would like to have the values in one column being set through an iterative function as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [0.4444, 25.4615],
     'col2': [0.5, 0.7],
     'col3': [7, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col4'] = df['col1'] * df['col3']/4

def func(df):
    a = np.exp(-df['col4'])

    n = 1
    while df['col2'] < a:
         a = a + df['col4'] * 4 / n
         n += 1
    return n

df['col5'] = func(df)
```

I get an error message "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." How can I run the function per row to solve the series/ambiguity problem?

EDIT: Added expected output.

```
out = {'col1': [0.4444, 25.4615],
       'col2': [0.5, 0.7],
       'col3': [7, 7],
       'col4': [0.7777, 44.557625],
       'col5': [0, 49]}
dfout = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

I am not sure what the values in col4 and col5 will be but according to the calculation I am trying to replicate those will be the values.

EDIT2: I had missed `n+=1` in the while loop. added it now.

EDIT3: I am trying to apply

```
f(0) = e^-col4
f(n) = col4 * f(n-1) / n for n > 0
```

until f > col2 and then return the value of n per row.

Comment: Can you maybe include example of desired output?

Comment: Your function still returns an int whereas you expect that col5 is assigned a series, should it be `return a` ? Also what is the expected semantics of `while df['col2'] < a` ?  do you want to only modify coefficients i that satisfy `df['col2'][i] < a[i]`?

Comment: Thank you @mcoav but that gives me the same reason. I want to see how many iterations I need to do before each row leaves the while loop, so to say.

Comment: So `while (df['col2'] < a).any():` should do the trick (if you do not mind that each row does the same number of iterations). (edit: apparently not, thanks for your edit)

Comment: That solves the ambiguity problem but I am far from the expected values. (I get 1, 1 while I am expecting 0, 49)

Answer (score 0):

Using the information you provided, this seems to be the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [0.4444, 25.4615],
     'col2': [0.5, 0.7],
     'col3': [7, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col4'] = df['col1'] * df['col3']/4

def func(df):
    n = 1
    return n

df['col5'] = func(df)
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that I have managed to convey what I am after. I had missed `n += 1` in the while loop. I have a function where f(0) = e^-col4 and f(n) = col4 * f(n-1) / n for n > 0 and would thus want to iterate while n increases until f() is larger than col2 and then return n.

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, here is an inefficient solution: after each iteration, keep track of which coefficient starts satisfying the condition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [0.4444, 25.4615],
     'col2': [0.5, 0.7],
     'col3': [7, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col4'] = df['col1'] * df['col3']/4

def func(df):
    a = np.exp(-df['col4'])

    n = 1

    ns = [None] * len(df['col2'])
    status = a > df['col2']        

    for i in range(len(status)):
        if ns[i] is None and status[i]:
            ns[i] = n

    # stops when all coefficients satisfy the condition
    while not status.all(): 
        a = a * df['col4'] * n
        status = a > df['col2']

        n += 1

        for i in range(len(status)):
            if ns[i] is None and status[i]:
                ns[i] = n

    return ns

df['col5'] = func(df)

print(df['col5'])
```